# Adding grunge with nodes in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, node-editor, effects

I am really new to blender and I am scrambling to learn as fast as possible however I am currently stuck. I have modeled a basic barrel and textured it as best as I can, I would like to add a dynamic kind of grunge to the barrel and I was assuming I could do this with nodes. The only tutorial I can find though is from back in 2015. Any ideas where I should start to achieve a grungy look? This is where I am currently.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What exactly do you mean by "dynamic kind of grunge"? Do you intend to animate it?

Comment: Thank you :) Eventually I will combine a number of assets that I am in the process of building to create a medieval style village animation. At least that is the hope. Maybe dynamic isn't the right word but I don't want it to be static and the same on duplicated objects

Comment: Sure. Textures created only with nodes are called *procedural textures*. Sites like [BlenderInsight](http://www.blenderinsight.com/) have a nice free(!) library and also a [facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/Blenderproceduraltextures/) (yeah, I know...) where you may find what you need. YT is also full of tutorials for procedural grunge look.

Comment: However, using an image texture [like this one from Poliigon](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/wood-planks-worn-33) is a great way to start.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69469/how-do-i-make-a-grunge-texture-appear-only-on-specific-parts-of-a-model https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75791/find-the-edges-of-checker-texture-for-adding-bumps-or-ridges https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35224/how-can-i-make-a-realistic-cement-shader-with-old-cracks-crumbling-paint-chippin/35402#35402 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-can-i-blend-two-textures-together-using-cycles

Comment: Thank you both @JachymMichal that has been very helpful! :)

Comment: Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos these are great posts to use as references.